# Most efficient or fastest way to write very often to a file with node fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Let's say I have an array with many keywords that I am passing one by one or in batches to an api and then write the response to csv using node fs. What approach will be faster or more efficient? `createWriteStream` or `appenFile` from `fs/promises`

createWriteStream

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'

const arr = ['many keywords',...]

(async () => {
  const writter = createWriteStream('results.csv', { flags: 'a' })

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // For each keyword access an api and write the response to a file
    const { data } = await axios(`https://someapi?request=${arr[i]}`)
    writter.write(`${data.response}\n`)
  }

})()
```

appendFile

```
import { appendFile } from 'fs/promises'

const arr = ['many keywords',...]

(async () => {
 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // For each keyword access an api and write the response to a file
    const { data } = await axios(`https://someapi?request=${arr[i]}`)
    await appendFile('results.csv', `${data.response}\n`)
  }

})()
```

Comment: Compared against the slowness of sequential http requests, it probably doesn't matter at all.

Comment: What if it is concurrently in batches?

Comment: Then using one `appendFile` call per batch is probably the simplest. A write stream should be faster in theory, since it doesn't have the overhead of repeatedly opening/closing the file, but to do it properly you would need to consider backpressure from a slow filesystem which isn't trivial to implement.

Comment: Make it correct, clear, concise and fast, in that order. Which one works? Do you have to deal with concurrency as @Álvaro pointed out?

Comment: Should I have to close the stream after each batch?

Comment: @Álvaro No, but you should wait until the stream is drained before starting the next batch, to avoid unnecessary buffering. See https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean drained?, what I am doing is for each batch `write` to the writeStream, then there is a timeout of 1 second for the next batch of 10